# get specific piece of a string

Tags: php, regex

I have sql statements as string;

```
a = "insert into table1 values('value1','value2','value3')"
b = "insert into table2 values('value4','value5','value6')"
c = "insert into table3 values('value7','value8','value9')"
```

I need function that split them and give me first value in statement(PHP 5.6)

```
a = splitFunction("insert into table1 values('value1','value2','value3')")//a ='value1'
b = splitFunction("insert into table2 values('value4','value5','value6')")//b='value4'
c = splitFunction("insert into table3 values('value7','value8','value9')")//c='value7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look on below code, It will return the desired result:

```
function splitFunction($str)
{
    $patterh = '~\'(.*?)\'~';
    preg_match($patterh, $str, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? $matches[1]:'no match';
}

echo splitFunction("insert into table1 values('value1','value2','value3')"); //output: value1
echo splitFunction("insert into table1 values('value4','value2','value3')"); //output: value4
echo splitFunction("insert into table1 values('value6','value2','value3')"); //output: value6
echo splitFunction("insert into table1"); //output: no match
```

Comment: Hello, it works but for next values paranteses it doesnt add new one but add previous one..
here is actuall scenario in my application:
$statement="INSERT INTO account VALUES('admin',...,'authentication_write'),('dashboard',...,'authentication_none')";
preg_match('~\'(.*?)\'~', $statement, $res);
//$res[0]='admin',$res[1]='admin'
but I expect //$res[0]='admin',$res[1]='dashboard'

Comment: according to your question you want to get first value in statement

Comment: @user5570680 change function to preg_match_all and then see the result, it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
$a = "insert into table1 values('value1','value2','value3')";
preg_match("#values\('([^']*)'#", $a, $res);
$a_value = $res[1];
var_dump($a_value);
```

Try this code (Ctrl+ENTER) : http://www.tehplayground.com/#s8l9tArRr